# How to change a Bootstrap-datetimepicker language during running

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i am using :

1. [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) V3.1.1
2. Boostrap Datetimepicker [(github link)](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)  [(guide)](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example1)

In my website the user can swap language. I need to change the language of the datetimepicker without reload the page. How can i do this? Do you have any suggestions?

---

**EDIT**:

At the beginning i am loading the right language using :

```
$('#banDateOneReal').datetimepicker({
     isRTL: false,
     autoclose: true,
     language: lang,
});
```

The problem is to change the language after the creation of the object. Imagine lang was *"en"* and I want *"fr"* when the user click in a button.

Thanks you a lot for any help

*(I am sorry about my poor english level)*

Comment: Try appending a `<script>` tag linked to js file for the specific language to the `<body>`, that (in theory) should update the language.

Comment: oh sorry. Maybe i had not explain it well. Edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way! Thanks to *DJDavid98* that gave to me some clues.

```
var tmp = $('#banDateOneReal').data('DateTimePicker').getDate();

$('#banDateOneReal').data('DateTimePicker').destroy();

$('#banDateOneReal').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
});

$('#banDateOneReal').data('DateTimePicker').setDate(tmp);
```

This code is going to destroy the datepicker item and create a new one with the good language.

There is no function yet to refresh it without destruction.